# Ajax Data response data not alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to alert some data using of ajax callback but not alerting.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script>
var mainObject = {
        myFunction: function() {
        $.ajax('ajax.php',function(data){
            alert(data);
            //$('#test123').html(data);
        });
    }
};
</script>
<div id="test123"></div>
<a href="javascript:mainObject.myFunction();">Click here</a>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php echo "Hello World!!!"; ?>
```

I am getting the response `Hello World!!!` but not alerting. Please check above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`

code:

```
var mainObject = {
        myFunction: function() {
        $.post('ajax.php',function(data){
            alert(data);
            //$('#test123').html(data);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `success` function in ajax

Try Like this

```
 $.ajax('ajax.php',{
      success : function(data){        // Response from the php file
                alert(data);
            }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,if you get success it will alert your data else it alert error message

```
$.ajax('ajax.php',success:function(data){
      alert(data);
    }
error:function()
{
alert("error");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script>
var mainObject = {
        myFunction: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            success:function(data){
            alert(data);
           }
        });
            //$('#test123').html(data);
        }
    }

</script>
<div id="test123"></div>
<a href="javascript:mainObject.myFunction();">Click here</a>
```